# Splitting polygon in half with lines in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, line, splitting

I have a polygon and a line, I want this line to split the polygon in half, i.e the same thing I could manually do with `"Split Parts"`.

I have tried every Geoprocessing tool; most answers I found suggest using a clip or intersection tool, but to me, that only results in a new line, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you checked this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/259737/63384

Comment: @ahmadhanb I hadn't seen that, but it doesn't help, because 3.12 doesn't appareantly have "Polygon-line intersection tool".

Comment: Should be something like lines to polygon.

Comment: @Chlodio It exists in QGIS 3.12, I have it. It is located under SAGA tools. Search for `Polygon-line intersection` and you should see it.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I did search for it, but I don't see SAGA at all when I open search bar for Processing Toolbox... I tried resetting and turning Processing Toolbox off and on, but SAGA doesn't appear.

Comment: @Chlodio Maybe you need to reinstall QGIS using OSGeo4W installer and add SAGA tool. Although [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202073/63384) is old but the process is same, please check it.

Comment: @ahmadhanb Well, thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you provide a graphical support of your desired output? The topology of your layers is not yet explicit.

Comment: There is 'Split with lines' algorithm in the toolbox. Did you try it? It seem like it does what you want.

Comment: @Ben Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chlodio, great! Glad it worked.