# (QGIS) Splitting vector polygon layer with vector line layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, clip, splitting

In QGIS, I have a layer of polygons (land parcels) and a layer of lines (outline of planned street). Can I slice the polygons along the line, creating new polygons from the "detached" parts?

[image: land parcels that have to be split]

If the street were a polygon, I could intersect both layers. Unfortunately, the street is a line layer that cannot be easily transformed to a polygon, since it has open ends, there is no defined "inside" or "outside".

I have searched StackExchange and Reddit, have tried all the QGIS vector tools, the SAGA vector tools, the Digitizing Tools plugin and the Clipper plugin, but no luck. My Python knowledge is near-nonexistent. What am I missing?

Using QGIS 2.18.24 (standard in my org, no chance of update for now).

Comment: The tool `split vector layer` should be available in 2.18: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools.html#split-vector-layer

Comment: @Erik, thank you, but the linked documentation does not seem complete. Having no prior experience with the QGIS console, I would appreciate some advice on how to use the command.

Comment: It should be a tool using the GUI, so open the toolbox and search for it.

Comment: You could use a buffer for your line, than you get a polygon - and you can do what you mentioned (intersect bot layers)

Comment: Have you checked the answer to this question: [How can I split a polygon by network line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/259737/63384)

Comment: Thank you @ahmadhanb! I did see a similar answer, but the one you linked was much more clear. Apparently, I had missed _selecting_ the line used for cutting, which is something I did not know I had to do. (Still learning, guys.) Problem solved, and I learned something new today. Thanks again!

Comment: @kolms Glad it solved the problem. You can upvote the answer so that it can help others having the same issue.